# External matplotlib viewer

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Whenever I try to display a plot using the ipython notebook with the module matplotlib no plotting is shown (I was expecting the familiar external viewer), instead I have to use the magic command `%matplotlib inline`, but I want to see the graph in an external viewer not into the notebook.

The same happens with other editors such as LightTable, the graph is shown into the editor not as an external graph.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Basic piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = x ** 2
plt.plot(x, y, 'r')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('title')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `%matplotlib qt` ?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named PySide`

Comment: Try installing `PySide`. [ Do `pip install pyside` ]

Comment: ``error: Error configuring shiboken```, I also did sudo apt-get shiboken but the error still continues

Comment: Try `pip install shiboken pyside`

Comment: Pyside installed, but the problem persists. I think it has something to do with the output of ```matplotlib.get_backend()```: 'module://IPython.kernel.zmq.pylab.backend_inline' , but not sure how to change the inline.